# Ruby Mechanize Parse Meta Tags

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, web-crawler, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize to crawl a bunch of web pages, and I'm having trouble getting at the meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-74.0100365">
<meta property="og:latitude" content="40.7199929">
```

I want to get the `og:longitude` and `og:latitude` parameters. What I tried isn't working, probably because the page is dynamically loaded or something. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

a.get(some_web_page) do |page|
  puts page.search("latitude").first.text
  puts page.search("longitude").first.text
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be:

```
page.at('meta[property="og:longitude"]')[:content]
page.at('meta[property="og:latitude"]')[:content]
```

note `:content` because it's the content attribute you want, not text.

Comment: It was working previously but now it is giving error "*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"